# Best Algorithm for Minimum Cost Maximum Flow?

Tags: algorithm

Can someone tell me which is the best algorithm for minimum cost maximum flow (and easy to implement) and from where to read will be helpful? I searched online and got names of many algorithms and unable to decide which one to study.

Comment: Easiest would be this one: https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/min_cost_flow.html#toc-tgt-3, basically edmonds karp, yet we find augmenting paths using bellman ford, with worst time complexity of `O(n^2 m^2)` there's also same algorithm where instead of bellman ford we use dijkstra with potentials it's faster but also quite complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience benchmarking MCF in an industry setting, there are three publicly available implementations that are competitive,

1. Andrew V Goldberg's cost scaling [implementation](https://github.com/iveney/cs2).
2. Coin-OR's Lemon library cost scaling [implementation](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/latest/a00102.html).
3. Coin-OR's Network Simplex [implementation](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/pub/doc/latest/a00269.html).

I would try those in that order if you are limited for time. Other honorable mentions are,

1. Google-OR's cost scaling [implementation](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/graph/min_cost_flow.cc). I haven't benchmarked this, but I'd expect it to be competitive with those above.
2. MCFClass has several [implementations](http://groups.di.unipi.it/optimize/Software/MCF.html) listed under various restricted licenses for commercial use. RelaxIV is very competitive but restrictive.

In terms of studying literature and a survey of competitive algorithms, the work of [Kirarly and Kovacs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.6381.pdf) are an excellent starting point.